# I am trying to load a modified pdf through the response of an ajax call. But always getting 404 error in Django python

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, pdf

I am very new to Django and infact its my first project using Django.

The `verify.html` is containing a PDF inside an `iframe` in the right side and in the left side there are input tags with values.
`Onclick` on any of these input tags executes `loadDoc()` and through AJAX call to backend Python function to highlight some text and save that highlighted PDF in URL:

> static_ocr/invoices/Grainger - Invoice_high.pdf

The PDF file is properly modified and saved in the specified location but with the response when I am trying to load the pdf, I am getting a 404 error:

> GET /verify/static_ocr/invoices/Grger - Invoice_high.pdf HTTP/1.1 404 4298

urls.py

```
path('verify/', views.map_invoice, name='verify'),
path('verify/highlight/', views.highlight, name='highlight')
```

views.py

```
def map_invoice is rendering verify.html page
def highlight is for highlighting the pdf and storing the same.
```

verify.html

```
function loadDoc(){
------------

$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '{{ 'highlight/' }}',
         data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}', text: val},
         success:  function(response){
                         alert(response);
                         $("#pdfview").attr("src", "static_ocr/invoices/Grger - Invoice_high.pdf");
                            
<iframe id="pdfview" src="{% static pdf_url %}" width="85%" height="750px"></iframe>
```

PDF is highlighted and stored but not getting displayed with error:

> "GET /verify/static_ocr/invoices/Grger - Invoice_high.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 4298

Comment: who serves the .pdf file after it is created (i.e. do you have a webserver that serves it, or are you expecting django to serve it?).  Or put another way, can you open the resulting url manually in a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HTTP-Status 404` indicates that the server could not find a file with the provided name/path. Therefore you should check if the file exists and/or the path is correct. The filename in your example contains spaces.

The solution to your probably will probably one of the two:

<s>1. Replace all occurrences of whitespaces with %20 within the file path or do not use whitespaces in the filepath at all</s>

2. Verify if the requested file is served from /static_ocr/invoices/Grger - Invoice_high.pdf instead of /verify/static_ocr/invoices/Grger - Invoice_high.pdf by adding a slash before ‘static_ocr’

**Update**

If you use spaces in the value of a src-attribute (tested with an iframe) the browser will URL-encode those spaces to %20.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried without whitespaces, but still the same error: 
/verify/static_ocr/invoices/Grger-Invoice.pdf  HTTP/1.1  404 4288

Comment: Wow...the second solution made it working....Thank you very much.
Could you please suggest, how to get a selected text from a PDF which is shown inside an <iframe>. I mean I can read a text from a direct PDF by Python, but how to recognize the selection on the pdf inside <iframe>.  
I am stuck with this part too. Checked many related posts but could not make it work yet. All your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If your task is just highlighting something within the PDF then you could mark the sentences on the server and save a manipulated version of the document which would then be served to the client.

If you want to read out what the clients user has selected then I think that is probably impossible if you render the PDF as is. You could look for a way to render the PDFs content as html somehow.
I didn't find any libraries for such a conversion that I would trust though. This solution might be kind of overcomplicated.